# Дозированная выдача контента пользователю в боте Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Создаю бота для телеграм. Концепция такая: пользователь вбивает ингредиенты блюда и мы по ключевым словам выдаем ссылку на рецепт, если он совпадает с запросом. Пока родил такой код и он работает:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search_recept(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаю поиск")
    user_query = message.text.lower().replace(',', '').split()

counter = 0
    for key, value in dict.items():
        for i in user_query:
            fuzzy = process.extractOne(i, value)
            if fuzzy[1] > 90:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0

        if counter == len(user_query):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, key + '\n Полный рецепт здесь ☝️ ')
```

Но имеет огромный недостаток. Он выдает все совпадения с нашей базой (Она в виде словаря. Где **key** - это ссылка на рецепт, а **value** - список с ключевыми словами рецепта. По ним и идет сравнение с запросом пользователя) А этих совпадений может быть десятки и пользователя бомбит этими рецептами.

**Задача** - сделать так, чтобы выдавало небольшое количество рецептов сразу (2-3) и дальше уже по запросу пользователя. Я еще новичок и сейчас в тупике. Подскажите пожалуйста, хотя бы направление куда двигаться. У меня есть идея создавать походу цикла отдельный словарь с совпавшими запросами и потом с него отправлять только три первых ключа. И удалять после отправки. А дальше как? Как принять от пользователя условный запрос 'хочу еще рецепты' и продолжить отправку. Да и кажется, это сильно замороченный вариант.  Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовать можно разными способами, одним из самых удобных и максимально предназначенных для этой задачи будет оператор `yield`.

Алгоритм таков - сохранить результат поиска в генератор и "выталкивать" итерируемые объекты из генератора. Сколько выводить за один раз для пользователя - решать вам, главное предусмотреть исключение `StopIteration`. Более подробнее об операторе `yield` можете посмотреть [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjaVrzOkpZk&ab_channel=%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), автор прекрасно объясняет как работает этот оператор.

Так как я использую `inline`-клавиатуру, то приходится где-то сохранять промежуточный результат. Имейте ввиду, что после перезапуска бота - словарь очистится.

(Может и можно обойтись без словаря, используя метод `bot.register_next_step_handler`; не тестировал, поэтому сказать точно не смогу)

Теперь сам пример:

```
from telebot import types
import telebot


ram = {}
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search_recept(message):
    k_yet = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)  # вывод кнопок в 1 колонку
    yet = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Хочу еще!', callback_data='yet')
    k_yet.add(yet)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начинаю поиск")
    user_query = message.text.lower().replace(',', '').split()
    # не могу понять из примера, как у вас работает поиск поэтому этот момент опускаю
    # например получаем результаты поиска, сохраняем в список find
    # на основе списка создаем генератор функцией output_data 
    # для каждого пользователя результат отправляем в словарь raw
    find = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
    ram.update({message.chat.id: output_data(find)})
    print(ram) # {123456789: <generator object output_data at 0x0297C404>}
    result1 = next(ram[message.chat.id])
    result2 = next(ram[message.chat.id])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вот список найденных результатов: \n{result1}\n{result2}', reply_markup=k_yet)


def output_data(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        yield i


# обработка callback клавиатуры
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def logic_inline(call):
    keyboard_yet = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    in_yet = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ЕЩЕ!', callback_data='yet!')
    keyboard_yet.add(in_yet)
    if call.data == 'yet' or call.data == 'yet!':
        try:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Вот тебе еще результат: \n{next(ram[call.message.chat.id])}',
                             reply_markup=keyboard_yet)
        except StopIteration:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Больше нет результатов')


bot.polling()
```

**Результат:**

[image: 2]